# startup with vpn connected

Tags: networking, startup, vpn

At startup, computer connects to network automatically. Can I also have computer start with vpn connected/connect as the next step automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use a VPN but there's an option in the Wireless Connection Settings.

Go to System Settings -> Network -> Wireless -> Settings

[image]

Comment: The user asked for "start with vpn connected/connect as the next step automatically".  How can the option "Automatically connect to VPN when using this coonection" not being considered what the user asked for?